# What is the proper way to populate table in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add data into sqlite table. I created string arrays like this

```
String idPriceArray = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
String priceSort = "Sort1, Sort2, Sort3, Sort4, Sort5";
String priceGrade = "A, B, C, D, E";
String priceDiameter = "45+, 40+, 35+, 32+, 28+";
String priceLength = "300, 250, 250, 220, 200";
String stumpPrice1 = "1900.00, 1300.00, 700.00, 450.00, 1400.00";
String stumpPrice2 = "248, 170, 144, 91, 59";
String roadPrice1 = "2000.00, 1400.00, 1200.00, 800.00, 550.00";
String roadPrice2 = "261, 183, 157, 104, 72";
String crustDeduction = "4, 4, 3, 3, 2";
```

And then I pass them into addPrices method like this.

```
public void addPrice() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        for (int i=0; i < idPriceArray.length(); i++) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(PRICE_SORT, priceSort);
            cv.put(PRICE_GRADE, priceGrade);
            cv.put(PRICE_DIAMETER, priceDiameter);
            cv.put(PRICE_LENGTH, priceLength);
            cv.put(PRICE_STUMP_KN, stumpPrice1);
            cv.put(PRICE_STUMP_EUR, stumpPrice2);
            cv.put(PRICE_ROAD_KN, roadPrice1);
            cv.put(PRICE_ROAD_EUR, roadPrice1);
            cv.put(PRICE_CRUST, crustDeduction);
            db.insert(TABLE_PRICE, null, cv);
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

Problem is that i get all sorts, grades and everything else in one row. When I display them in layout I get like this:
Sort: Sort1, Sort2, Sort3.. 
Grades: A, B, C, D, E.  
But I want to get it like this: 
Sort: Sort1 
Grades: A 
And all like this. 
 I would like to know what is the proper way to populate table like this?

**Edit:** 
This is my getAllPrices method. I think that is also good.

```
  public ArrayList<Price> getAllPrices() {
        ArrayList<Price> priceList = new ArrayList<Price>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRICE + " ORDER BY " + PRICE_ID;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Price price = new Price();
                price.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
                price.setSort(cursor.getString(1));
                price.setGrade(cursor.getString(2));
                price.setDiameter(cursor.getString(3));
                price.setLength(cursor.getString(4));
                price.setStumpPrice_1(cursor.getString(5));
                price.setStumpPrice_2(cursor.getString(6));
                price.setRoadPrice_1(cursor.getString(7));
                price.setRoadPrice_2(cursor.getString(8));
                price.setDeduction(cursor.getString(9));
                priceList.add(price);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return priceList;
    }
```

And in my layout I created a base adapter in which I'm displaying the data. 
Could it be i still something messed up with adding into table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created `Arrays`. You have created `Strings`.

First create arrays like this -

```
String priceSort[] = new String[]{"Sort1", "Sort2", "Sort3", "Sort4", "Sort5"};
```

Do this for all your Arrays. Then in your `for` loop insert each item separately in each row. Notice how I've used `i` value of for loop to get the values from arrays.

```
for (int i=0; i < idPriceArray.length(); i++) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(PRICE_SORT, priceSort[i]);
        cv.put(PRICE_GRADE, priceGrade[i]);
        cv.put(PRICE_DIAMETER, priceDiameter[i]);
        cv.put(PRICE_LENGTH, priceLength[i]);
        cv.put(PRICE_STUMP_KN, stumpPrice1[i]);
        cv.put(PRICE_STUMP_EUR, stumpPrice2[i]);
        cv.put(PRICE_ROAD_KN, roadPrice1[i]);
        cv.put(PRICE_ROAD_EUR, roadPrice1[i]);
        cv.put(PRICE_CRUST, crustDeduction[i]);
        db.insert(TABLE_PRICE, null, cv);
    }
```

After this you'll end up with 5 rows in your sql table with each row corresponding to 1 item.

Comment: Done that, but layout is empty. Should I change my Price class also? I mean getters and setters?

Comment: I don't see any Price class objects. Where are you using them?

Comment: I use them to get price values form my Price table and display them in layout. Should I post you object from Price class. It is simple constructor, getters and setters methods.  I convert my idPriceArray(which are id-s) same as you say for priceSort[ ]. And then i for loop I have `for (int i=0; i < idPriceArray.length; i++)` . Could it be in this problem?

Comment: Price class is perfect. Now post how you retrieve data from sqlite and make price objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105545/discussion-between-jyotman-singh-and-rubydigger19).

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your `String`s into separate entries first. For example:

```
String[] priceSortArr = priceSort.split(",");
//Repeat for the rest...

public void addPrice() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        //Worth calling trim() to remove any leading and trailing white space
        cv.put(PRICE_SORT, priceSortArr[i].trim());
        //etc.
        db.insert(TABLE_PRICE, null, cv);
    }
    db.close();
}
```

**Edit:** Or ofcourse you can just write them as arrays in the first place:

```
 String[] priceSortArr = new String[] { "Sort1", "Sort2", "Sort3", "Sort4", "Sort5" };
```